# How can I convert avsc files to avdl files?

Tags: avro

It is common to convert avro `avdl` files (idl files) to `avsc` files (schema files).  I want to convert in the other direction, from `avsc` to `avdl`, because I have some avsc files created manually and want to see them in the simpler and prettier avdl format.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out the java utility I wrote: [SchemaUtils.writeIdlProtocol](https://github.com/zolyfarkas/spf4j/blob/master/spf4j-avro-components/spf4j-avro/src/main/java/org/spf4j/avro/schema/SchemaUtils.java#L176), it basically allows you to save a bunch of ovro schema's into a avdl file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [avsc2avdl](https://github.com/wjur/avsc2avdl) tool (author here). It might not work all cases, because it's still in progress, but I use it at work and it does it's job.

Comment: Would you agree to bring this functionality to `savro` ?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70723110/4032515

Answer (score 0):

See also `savro` https://github.com/irajhedayati/savro#avro-schema-to-avro-idl

> **Avro Schema to Avro IDL**
> You also can convert an Avro schema to an Avro IDL.

```scala
import ca.dataedu.savro._
import org.apache.avro.Schema

val schema: Schema = ???
val idl: String = new AvroSchemaToIdl(schema, "ProtocolName").convert()
```